# Как импортировать массив объектов из .js-файла во vue-файл?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Согласно заданию, мне необходимо было создать моки (массив объектов с параметрами студентов- имени, группы и так далее), затем этот массив мне требовалось импортировать в vue  файл, где лежит компонент карточки студента. Карточка студента - элемент на странице, который выводит на экран данные о студенте, которые должны браться из помянутого файла выше. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как мне импортировать этом массив вида `const STUDENTS =[{name: "john doe", group: "333"},{name: "jake maddsen", group: "334"}, ... ]` из файла student.js во  vue  файл  studentCard.vue.

Чтобы это решить, я попыталась прописать `export` перед `STUDENTS` так же пыталась сделать через `export default STUDENTS` , после  чего я переходила в нужный vue  файл и писала `import {STUDENTS} from 'student.js'` это не срабатывало а  IDE подчеркивала имя импортируемого файла красным и уведомляла `could not find declaration file for module /student.js; student.js implicity has an 'any' type`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

Файл **student.js**:

```
export const STUDENTS = [];
```

Файл **studentCard.vue**:

```
import {STUDENTS} from './student';
```